# Mounting Android Phone on Ubuntu/Server/Raspberry Pi not working even after installing gmtp and mtp-tools

Tags: usb, android, raspberrypi, mtp

After mounting an Android Phone as a USB / MTP device successfully on my desktop Ubuntu (22.04.1 LTS), I switched to a Raspberry Pi 4 w/a fresh download of the Ubuntu/Server/Raspberry Pi image (Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS).  I connected the Android Phone and did not see any of the directories / files I saw when the phone was connected to my Ubuntu desktop.

I then installed both "gmtp" and "mtp-tools" and rebooted the Raspberry Pi.  I still did not see any new directories / files.  I check and found a new /dev/*mtp* device on the Raspberry Pi when the phone was connected.  But I have never seen the expected directories / files under the /run/user/... directory.

I then monitored the /var/log/syslog both on the working Ubuntu desktop and the not working Rraspberry Pi.  They both start the same by "seeing" the new USB Android Phone device.  But the Ubuntu desktop then apparently "audited" the phone which (I assume) caused the phone to interrogate the user for permissions to share files.

Apparently the Raspberry Pi is missing this "audit" step.  Could this be yet another missing MTP package?  Or a service that is not activated?

All the packages w/"mtp" in there name on the Raspberry Pi:

```
$ sudo dpkg -l | grep mtp
ii  gmtp                            1.3.11-3build1                          arm64        simple file transfer program for MTP based devices
ii  libmtp-common                   1.1.19-1build1                          all          Media Transfer Protocol (MTP) common files
ii  libmtp-runtime                  1.1.19-1build1                          arm64        Media Transfer Protocol (MTP) runtime tools
ii  libmtp9:arm64                   1.1.19-1build1                          arm64        Media Transfer Protocol (MTP) library
ii  mtp-tools                       1.1.19-1build1                          arm64        Media Transfer Protocol (MTP) library tools
$
```

Comment: Similar question posted by OP on RaspberryPi.SE: [Does the Raspberry Pi 4 running Ubuntu/Server (22.04.1 LTS) support Android Phones (USB / MTP)?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/139846/23142)

Comment: Yes, but it is not a cut and past.  They are worded differently to addressed the different user groups.  Also, the  RaspberryPi.SE post was not made until 80% of the expected views (13 out of (currently) 16) occurred.  It is odd that you found this.  Are you a Linux & Android enthusiast?  Perhaps you can contribute by answering the question?

Comment: I found them by chance from monitoring the [tag:android] tag network-wide. Unfortunately, I don't have much experience with drive mounting.

Comment: I'm not sure if what Ubuntu Desktop does with MTP devices is "mounting".  I think desktop Ubuntu performs a service that show what is available through MTP and copies files if you need to look at them.  The frustrating part ... it works on Ubuntu Desktop but not on Ubuntu Server for Raspberry Pi.   So far I've discovered the UDEV rules on Ubuntu Server for Raspberry Pi is almost empty.  But even if I copy the UDEV rules for MTP Android phones from Ubuntu Desktop to Ubuntu Raspberry Pi, the Raspberry Pi still does not work like Ubuntu Desktop.